# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification From Android App

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications from an android device to multiple android devices and I am using FCM to send notifications but the problem is I am not receiving any thing. I followed some tutorials and as well as some links here on stackoverflow but I don't understand what am I doing wrong. I tried to send notification using retrofit and okhttp but I can't seem to generate the notification. From Firebase Console I can generate the notification but not from android app.

## Using Retrofit

### Retrofit code

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build();
API api = retrofit.create(API.class);
PushNotificationModel pushNotificationModel = new PushNotificationModel(
        "/topics/Receive",
        new NotificationModel(
                "Mobile",
                "I am ready for you"
        )
);
Call<PushNotificationModel> call = api.sendNotification(pushNotificationModel);
call.enqueue(new Callback<PushNotificationModel>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<PushNotificationModel> call, Response<PushNotificationModel> response) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: Code: " + response.code() /*+ " Response: " + new Gson().toJson(response)*/);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<PushNotificationModel> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
    }
});
```

### POJO classes

```
public class PushNotificationModel {
    private String to;
    private NotificationModel notification;

    public PushNotificationModel(String to, NotificationModel notification) {
        this.to = to;
        this.notification = notification;
    }
}

public class NotificationModel {
    private String title, body;

    public NotificationModel(String title, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }
}
```

### Interface

```
public interface API {

    @Headers({
            "Authorization:key=AAAAO-53MSs:APA91bFR...JNL7GjX1D",
            "Content-Type:application/json"
    })
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Call<PushNotificationModel> sendNotification(@Body PushNotificationModel pushNotificationModel);
}
```

## SOLUTION

I was able to solve the problem by cleaning and rebuilding the project and sometimes on first initial deployment of project I wasn't able to receive notification so closing the app, removing from multitasking bar and re-opening the app solved the problem I was able to receive the notifications properly :). Doesn't matter what you use either volley or retrofit works on both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will send notification to a group of device that are subscribed to the topic called `topicName`.

```
//send notification to other user
public void sendNotificationToUser() {
        JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            mainObj.put("to", "/topics/" + topicName); // topicName = your topic name
            JSONObject notificationObj = new JSONObject();
            notificationObj.put("title", "Add your title");
            notificationObj.put("body", "Body section");
            mainObj.put("notification", notificationObj);

            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
                    mainObj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {

                    Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                    header.put("content-type", "application/json");
                    header.put("authorization", "key="+key);//key = your Database Key
                    return header;
                }
            };
            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
            //
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }

}
//send notification to other user above
```

For receiving notification add this `FCMService.class` to your project

```
public class FCMService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //message is recieved. Do whatever you want to do 
}

@Override
public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
            FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("your topic name here").addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {//subcribe again if some error occured
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        }
    });
    super.onNewToken(s);
}

}
```

Don't forget to register in manifest. Add below code inside `manifest>application`

```
        <service
        android:name=".FCMService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

**Adding `firebase-key` in app source code isn't a good idea. You can use `Firebase Cloud function`[have to upgrade project to use Function]**

Comment: You subscribed to topic on FCMService in onNewToken why?

Comment: It's not necessary. I had followed a tutorial when I did this coding. I might have done this mistakenly. Check without that part, it should work

Comment: Okay let me test the code I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest); unable to find this object where have you initialized this object?

Comment: Initialize like this `RequestQueue  requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);` Also add this library if you haven't added 
    `implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'`

Comment: I am using androids volley does that make a difference?

Comment: Its not working still no notification received, I am able to send the notification from the firebase console

Comment: I am using this code in my project and it's working fine. Make sure that you are subscribed to that topic in which topic you are sending notification

Comment: Subscribe from a mobile[1] or emulator, then run above code from another phone[2] or emulator. You will receive notification in mobile[1]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230031/discussion-between-muhammad-yousuf-and-unknown-2433).

Comment: I have moved this to chat please take a look over there

Comment: If your problem is solved, mark my answer as `accepted`

Comment: Done bro :) Thanks once again :)